# SA default password SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server, centos, passwords, sa, sql-server-linux

I installed SQL Server 2017 on Linux on a CentOS 7 derivate. Now I want to login with the command: "sqlcmd -S 172.0.0.1 -U SA". But I never set up a password. How am I able to login to the SQL Server? Root password is also not working. Could it be that the problem is somewhere earlier?

I tried as well to connect with "root", "sa" and the root password, also with Blank password and "Password123", according to old default passwords.

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa
```

I get the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error hasile establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance nam and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: The error message isn't because you've got the username or password incorrect but because sqlcmd cannot connect to the SQL Server instance. Is SQL Server running? Is it on the standard port (tcp/1433)? Assuming you're running SQL Server inside docker, have you mapped a port from the docker container to the host?

Comment: Thank you, I could now configure it correctly. The MS documentation is a bit misleading because the different steps are not in one place.